# Can iPad Pro Smart Connector be used for serial communication

Tags: ipad, serial-communication

Does anyone know if it's possible to use the 'smart connector' on an iPad pro for serial communication, or is it only accessible by big device manufacturers?

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the hardware dev docs you need to be a member of Apple's [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).  You need to be a [company](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#2-1) to apply, and they have to approve your application. I'm not sure whether you need to be a "big" company, as they don't say that specifically, but you probably need to convince them you are credibly in the position to take an accessory device to market.

However... the [FAQ does say](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#4-5)

> **I want to develop an MFi accessory for personal use. Can I join the MFi Program?**
>
> No. We recommend that you use a third-party hobbyist solution which will allow you to connect iOS devices to serial devices and to write iOS apps that communicate with these serial devices.

So it looks like there is an aftermarket device that you can buy to get access to the serial port.

Comment: Thanks, I was guessing that the MFi program might be required for that. I'm not looking for just any serial communication, which can be achieved through the Redpark adapter or using Peertalk. I'm trying to find out about the Smart Connector specifically.